# "The writing is on the wall for the wall itself." Does the word-play work?

Tags: word-play, pun, idioms-in-context

I know the idiom "the (hand)writing on the wall", so I make the sentence. However, I'm not sure.

Comment: :-) Yes, it makes perfect sense if the wall is going to be demolished. And the word-play does work. Not "*hand*writing" though. The expression is "the writing is on the wall" or "the writing's on the wall", and we rarely change the wording of these old expressions.

Comment: With graffiti, and someone approaching with a sand blaster or a pot of paint, the writing is on the wall for the writing on the wall :-)